# mod_rewrite works incorrectly on apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache2.4

I have used other host before, all works fine, but now I have changed it to new one. On new host is installed apache 2.4.

I have the next rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]

        RewriteRule manage/ajax/(.*?)$ manage/ajax/index.php [QSA,L]
        RewriteRule manage/json/(.*?)$ manage/json/index.php [QSA,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(.+)$
        RewriteRule ckfinder/(.*?)$ ckfinder/index.html [QSA,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(.+)$
        RewriteRule manage/(.*?)/$ manage/index.php [QSA,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(.+)$
        RewriteRule ajax/(.+?) ajax/index.php [QSA,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(.+)$
        RewriteRule api/(.*?) /api/index.php [QSA,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(.+)$
        RewriteRule (.*) index.php
</IfModule>
```

When I try to access for example **/manage/** it show me index page, but if I will add some additional data to the path it will show me what I required. For example: **/manage/some_data** - Will work fine. But I want to access correct directory by just **/manage/**.

Comment: Just use `DirectoryIndex index.php` at top of your .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Change this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(.+)$
RwriteRule manage/(.*?)/$ manage/index.php [QSA,L]
```

To

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(.+)$
RwriteRule manage(/.*)?$ manage/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The same result, nothing was changed.

Comment: Absolutely sure you typed it correctly? The regex should work. See here: http://regex101.com/r/jN1jA8/2

Comment: I don't think that problem is in regex, because my rules works fine on old server. I think there are problem in logic, maybe something changed in new apache with mod_rewrite?

Comment: Well your old regex didn't look correct, it would only have matched what you were seeing i.e. `manage/some_data` or `manage//`, the `(.*?)` section would've prevented `manage/` from being a match.

Comment: Okey, maybe my regex was also wrong, but your regex haven't fixed my problem. Also, as you can see there api, ajax and other. I have the same problem with all this queries. I think there are some problem in the main logic.

Comment: I have found a comment for my first post, `DirectoryIndex index.php` fixed it.